# Javscript: For every image click show modal with image zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm currently working on a simple image modal that should show only an image zoom with a close button.
I have a markup generated from my CMS in which the a tag can be configurated to have an extra class "lightbox" as an attribute which should then trigger the lightbox script.

However, currently it seems to only work for the first image that's loaded. When I click on another image it shows the same image source from the first one and I'm not sure how to fix it. Do all the images need to be looped over first?

My CMS generates a markupa  for the images like this in the DOM (image is a placeholder):

```
<a href="image1.png" class="lightbox">
  <img class="image-embed-item" src="image" >
</a>

<a href="image1.png" class="lightbox">
   <img class="image-embed-item" src="image" >
</a>

<a href="image1.png" class="lightbox">
    <img class="image-embed-item" src="image" >
</a>
```

In my default layout I then add the markup for the lightbox modal:

```
<div id="imagemodal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close">&times;</div>
        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // add imageresource id to loaded image
    $(".image-embed-item").attr("id", "imageresource");

    // add data-toggle class to all lightbox elements
    $(".lightbox").attr("data-toggle", "lightbox");

    // click event for data toggle
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    // use image source from clicked image
        $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('src'));
        $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $(document).on('click', $('.closeModal'), function (event) {
        // close function
    });
});
```

Here is my css:

```
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same id for all `.image-embed-item` in:

```
 $(".image-embed-item").attr("id", "imageresource");
```

And then use `$('#imageresource').attr('src')` to set the preview.
That's why it always show the first image in the modal. You can solve it by changing `$('#imageresource').attr('src')` to `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`. Something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // add data-toggle class to all lightbox elements
  $(".lightbox").attr("data-toggle", "lightbox");

  // click event for data toggle
  $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  // use image source from clicked image
    $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $(document).on('click', $('.closeModal'), function (event) {
    // close function
  });
});
```